# getting the xpath for crawling a video url

Tags: html, python-3.x, xml, xpath, web-crawler

I want to get the xpath of the video url from this [webpage](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/981619939/let-there-be-color?ref=category_newest) so I can download its video using python.

What I do is that I press F12 and find the video section and under video class, I right-click on the source and copy xpath. but I can not find the xpath for the video url. The xpath I get are as follows:

```
//*[@id="react-project-header"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/video/source[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extracting the url with this xpath expression

```
//*[@id="react-project-header"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/video/source[2]/@src
```

Edit: How to get there

Initially, I got the the path the same way you did - through the Developer tab. I changed the end part from `source[1]` to `source[2]` because that's where the HD version of the video resides, so why not? More importantly, your actual target (the url of the video) was - to use formal xpath terminology - an attribute value of an attribute of a node. In this case, the node is `source[2]`, the attribute is `src` and the value is the desired url. To select an attribute value of an attribute of a node, one has to use the `@` operator, as in

```
node/@attribute
```

or, in this case

```
[xpath to]source[2]/@src
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you please guide me on how you got this xpath?

Comment: I have another question. So, I followed your instructions and it worked but it does not work for another url that I want to get. From this website (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/travel-tripod-by-peak-design?ref=discovery_category_newest) I want to get this url (https://www.youtube.com/embed/8f82p6Do9cc?showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&widget_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kickstarter.com%2Fprojects%2Fpeak-design%2Ftravel-tripod-by-peak-design%3Fref%3Ddiscovery_category_newest&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.embedly.com&widgetid=1) and the xpath I get is: //*[@id="player"]/@src

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam - Per SO policy, you should post it as a separate question. I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: This is the link of the question. thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256717/i-can-not-retrieve-the-url-i-want-although-i-give-the-xpath