# I can not retrieve the url I want although I give the xpath

Tags: html, python-3.x, xml, xpath

I want to get the xpath of the video url from this [webpage](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/travel-tripod-by-peak-design?ref=discovery_category_newest) so I can download [this video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/8f82p6Do9cc?showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&widget_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kickstarter.com%2Fprojects%2Fpeak-design%2Ftravel-tripod-by-peak-design%3Fref%3Ddiscovery_category_newest&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.embedly.com&widgetid=1) using python.

What I do is that I press F12 and find the video section and under video class, I right-click on the source and copy xpath. But I cannot retrieve the url using python. The xpath I get is:

```
//*[@id="player"]/@src
```

And here is the python code I use:

```
url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/peak-design/travel-tripod-by-peak-design?ref=discovery_category_newest'
res = requests.get(url=url)
tree = html.fromstring(res.text)
video_url = tree.xpath('//*[@id="player"]/@src')
print(video_url)
```